# 301 redirect to handle new URL and changed file types

Tags: regex, apache

I have a 301 redirect problem to solve.  I am porting a web app from a Windows host to a new Linux host.  In the process I am collapsing a sub-domain into the main domain (http://subdomain.example.com => http://www.example.com), Also I have rewritten the application from .Net to PHP, so all the file types have changed (.aspx files => .php files).  I have come across a solution to manage the domain-change part of the problem, using the .htaccess to redirect:

```
redirect 301 / http://subdomain.example.com/
```

I have also found this snippet which should take care of the file-type problem:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.aspx$ http://www.example.com$1.php
```

My question now is how to implement it.  My first instinct is to insert them both into the new web root's .htaccess file, but I suspect that's not the right way to do it.  Any suggestions?

EDIT: ISSUE SOLVED -- SEE ANSWER BELOW

Comment: Why don't you paste your solution into the actual answer box and mark it as the answer?

Comment: I didn't know that was legal.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are really two steps to the solution. First I recreated the subdomain on my new server even though no content is to be served through that domain. In the subdomain root folder I created one .htaccess file and entered just the 301 redirect to route the request to the main domain where the content now resides:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Then I created another .htaccess file in the root directory of the actual site to translate the file type once the re-redirected traffic makes a request, using a RedirectMatch to translate .aspx file requests to .php file requests:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.aspx$ http://www.example.com$1.php
```

And it works perfectly.